# Replace company name in copyright section for the existing project in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode, xcode7

Currently the Copyright files looks like this:

//  Created by Jon Doe on 4/2/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 My Old Company Name. All rights reserved.

I want o change it to something like this:

//  Created by Appleseed on 4/2/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2016 My New Company Name. All rights reserved

I found a lot of answers to change the name for the New Projects/Files by changing the organization name or changing the name in address book. I was looking for something for an existing projects. Something similar to Copyright profile offered by Android Studio.

Comment: Just search your existing word and replace it with new word.

Comment: Thank for the quick response. Isn't there a better way to do that similar to Copyright Profile for Xcode.

Comment: If there is any way for that then I want to know.. :)

Answer (score 2):

For established project source files, use the old-fashioned global text search and replace via Xcode's `Find navigator`.

Newly created files will adhere to the `organization` setting in the `project document` section of the `file inspector`.

Answer (score 0):

For an old project, use the Attribute Inspector to change the existing organisation name to be used for new files.

For any existing files, use Xcode search feature, change to replace, add the old content, and the new which you want to set, and replace all files.